# Merge rows containing same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server. I have the following table:

```
+----------------+
|       ID       |
+----------------+
| A2             |
| B4, F1         |
| B3             |
| C2, A2         |
| H4, K0, Z3, F1 |
| A1             |
+----------------+
```

My goal is to merge the rows containing at least one common ID.

The expected result is:

```
+--------------------+
|         ID         |
+--------------------+
| A2, C2             |
| B4, F1, H4, K0, Z3 |
| B3                 |
| A1                 |
+--------------------+
```

Which query should I use?

Here is one fiddle with the test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1961c/1

Comment: What if you have:  `A, B`, `B, C`, `C, D`?

Comment: I would, in truth, look at fixing your design here. Storing Delimited data in your database is rarely a good idea.

Comment: They would all be merged into a single string  A, B, C, D

Comment: What is your MSSQL server version?

Comment: I am using Version 2017