# Merge groups if they contain the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table:

```
+-----+----+---------+
| grp | id | sub_grp |
+-----+----+---------+
|  10 | A2 |       1 |
|  10 | B4 |       2 |
|  10 | F1 |       2 |
|  10 | B3 |       3 |
|  10 | C2 |       4 |
|  10 | A2 |       4 |
|  10 | H4 |       5 |
|  10 | K0 |       5 |
|  10 | Z3 |       5 |
|  10 | F1 |       5 |
|  10 | A1 |       5 |
|  10 | A  |       6 |
|  10 | B  |       6 |
|  10 | B  |       7 |
|  10 | C  |       7 |
|  10 | C  |       8 |
|  10 | D  |       8 |
|  20 | A  |       1 |
|  20 | B  |       1 |
|  20 | B  |       2 |
|  20 | C  |       2 |
|  20 | C  |       3 |
|  20 | D  |       3 |
+-----+----+---------+
```

Within every `grp`, my goal is to merge all the `sub_grp` sharing at least one `id`.

More than 2 `sub_grp` can be merged together.

The expected result should be:

```
+-----+----+---------+
| grp | id | sub_grp |
+-----+----+---------+
|  10 | A2 |       1 |
|  10 | B4 |       2 |
|  10 | F1 |       2 |
|  10 | B3 |       3 |
|  10 | C2 |       1 |
|  10 | A2 |       1 |
|  10 | H4 |       2 |
|  10 | K0 |       2 |
|  10 | Z3 |       2 |
|  10 | F1 |       2 |
|  10 | A1 |       2 |
|  10 | A  |       6 |
|  10 | B  |       6 |
|  10 | B  |       6 |
|  10 | C  |       6 |
|  10 | C  |       6 |
|  10 | D  |       6 |
|  20 | A  |       1 |
|  20 | B  |       1 |
|  20 | B  |       1 |
|  20 | C  |       1 |
|  20 | C  |       1 |
|  20 | D  |       1 |
+-----+----+---------+
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the test values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13666c/2

I am trying to solve this either with a stored procedure or queries.

This is an evolution from my previous problem: [Merge rows containing same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574429/merge-rows-containing-same-values)

Comment: will you be able to split the values based on id like one A2 entry will be stored in one table (with A2->primary key value) and other A2 entries will be in another table (A2-> foreign key value). In this way, the context of your problem will be more clear

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, what if there is more than two entries for A2.

Comment: that won't provide a direct solution. If id column is made primary key in one and foreign key in another then that might provide a way to join these two tables and pull up the result you expect

Comment: Please clarify the merging rules. It is not clear why 10/B4 results in 2 while  20/D results in 1 (instead of 3).

Comment: To simplify, there is no rules, just put a random one (1 or 3)

Comment: Isn't this just a simple `group by`?

Comment: There has to be rules. "sharing at least one id" is a rule. Output doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

### My understanding of the problem

Merge sub_grp (for a given grp) if any one of the IDs in one sub_grp match any one of the IDs in another sub_grp. A given sub_grp can be merged with only one other (the earliest in ascending order) sub_grp.

### Disclaimer

This code may work. Not tested as OP did not provide DDLs and data scripts.

### Solution

```
UPDATE final
SET sub_grp = new_sub_grp
FROM
    -- For each grp, sub_grp combination return a matching new_sub_grp
    ( SELECT a.grp, a.sub_grp, MatchGrp.sub_grp AS new_sub_grp
    FROM tbl AS a
        -- Inner join will exclude cases where there are no matching sub_grp and thus nothing to update.
        INNER JOIN
            -- Find the earliest (if more than one sub-group is a match) matching sub-group where one of the IDs matches
            ( SELECT TOP 1 grp, sub_grp
            FROM tbl AS b
            -- b.sub_grp > a.sub_grp - this will only look at the earlier sub-groups avoiding the "double linking"
            WHERE b.grp = a.grp AND b.sub_grp > a.sub_grp AND b.ID = a.ID 
            ORDER BY grp, sub_grp ) AS MatchGrp ON 1 = 1
    -- Only return one record per grp, sub_grp combo
    GROUP BY grp, sub_grp, MatchGrp.sub_grp ) AS final
```

You can re-number sub groups afterwards as a separate update statement with the help of [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function.